# Can I conclude from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ being convergent that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{u_n}{n}$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

So the question is the following statement correct?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n < \infty \implies
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{u_n}{n} < \infty.
$$
I think the answer is not, however I cannot find a counterexample or prove it otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** What if $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n+1)}$?

Answer (score 3):

It's not true generally, but perhaps could be *made* true under certain conditions. For example, if all $u_n > 0$, then
$$
(-1)^n \frac{u_n}{n}<\frac{u_n}{n} < u_n, \quad \forall n\ge 2,
$$
so your statement  would hold.

Additionally, this suggests a good place to start looking for counter-examples if you want to claim it always holds.